# Windows not pointing to newer upgraded version of PIP (upgraded using get-pip.py)

Tags: python, pip

I have 2 Pip versions installed on my Windows 10 system. I had upgraded 8.2 version using get-pip.py file and it upgraded successfully to 9.0 version, but when i am hitting pip --version in command prompt its showing 8.2 only. Is there any way I can tell windows to look up for newer version? I have Python 2.7 installed. Should i upgrade that too?

I also tried using new environment variable for newer version's directory. 
I have anaconda package installed on my system.
Directory for pip 8.2: C:\Python27\Scripts
Ditectory for pip 9.0: C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way

```
doskey pip=C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pip $
```

However, I would suggest to simply take out one of the installs and use only one.